# How do i merge lists based upon an element in python?

Tags: python, list

I am new to python so a simplified explanation would be appreciated  :)

I have been assigned a task which requires me to take a csv file, with two columns, the first for a name and the second for a score. With this data i would like to create a single list containing this data for every row in the csv file. so it should look something like this:

```
list1 = [['Bob Smith', '7'],['Bob Smith', '9'],['Bob Smith', '4'],['James Johnson', '3'],['James Johnson', '6']]
```

I have managed to get that far however the task then requires me to group names and scores together and put them into a new list. This is what it should look like:

```
List2 = [['Bob Smith', '7', '9', '4'],['James Johnson', '3', '6']]
```

Essentially it is taking all of the scores from elements that have the same name and grouping them together in a new list.

As i am new to python i am finding this a little difficult to comprehend would someone be able to point me in the direction to the solution for my problem?

Comment: Store the names as keys in a dictionary then store each score number as a value in the dictionary. Recreate the list structure you need by using the dictionary you just made.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a dictionary https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to create a  mapping from names to a *list of values*. For example:

```
 import collections

 list1 = [
     ['Bob Smith', '7'],
     ['Bob Smith', '9'],
     ['Bob Smith', '4'],
     ['James Johnson', '3'],
     ['James Johnson', '6']]

  names = collections.defaultdict(list)                                                                                                                                                                                                        

  for k, v in list1:
      names[k].append(v)

  print names
```

Prints

```
{'James Johnson': ['3', '6'], 'Bob Smith': ['7', '9', '4']}
```

Comment: I understand the concept you are suggesting however i am unsure how i would translate this into code. Could you give me an example of how to use it?

Comment: Mhm, alright, I added a working python code to build the dict...

Comment: You may want to show an additional example or introduce the use of [```collections.defaultdict```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) since all the values will be ```list```s.

Comment: @wwii Thanks updated :p

Comment: Please explain why ```extend``` was used instead of ```append```.  also it may be more idiomatic to use _tuple unpacking_ in the ```for``` statement - ```for k,v in list1```.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're reading this file in from CSV, but you could do something like this:

```
with open(r'c:\debug\file.txt', 'r') as f:
  lines = [l.strip().split(',') for l in f.readlines()]    # convert each line to a python list
  names = { l[0] : [l[0]] for l in lines }  # create a dictionary mapped to each "name" in the CSV
  for l in lines:
    names[l[0]].append(l[1])

list2 = names.values()
```

The following result for `print list2:`

```
[['James Johnson', '3', '6'], ['Bob Smith', '7', '9', '4']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with a single function:

1. Open your document
2. Read each line, storing them as a list
3. Store each of these [name,number] lists in a meta-list
4. dissect and sort the meta-list into a dictionary

If you want to test this code, just do the following:

1. copy/paste this code into a file
2. Add "print(names)" to the end of the file
3. run sort('yourFile.csv')

.

```
#Create a function to open and sort through the .csv file
def sort(fileName):
    #Open the file
    with open(fileName) as file:
        #create your first list to hold the information
        lists = []
        #read each line in the list
        for each in file:
            #separate each name from its respective number
            (name,number) = each.strip().split(',')
            #store them both in a second list
            #add each "name and number" to the original list
            list2 = [name,number]
            lists.append(list2)

        #create a dictionary to hold your new datasets
        names = {}
        #checking for the name and numbers previously stated
        for name, number in lists:
            #if the name isn't already in your dictionary, "names"
            #then add it to the dictionary, and its respective number
            if name not in names:
                  names[name] = [number]
            #but if the name IS in the dictionary, add the new number to it.
            else:
                  names[name].append(number)
```